# What is relationship with Megami Tensei franchises

Tags: persona, shin-megami-tensei

like in the title said what's the relationship with Megami Tensei franchises? Megami Tensei have large franchises there are

1. Devil Children
2. Devil Summoner
3. Devil Survivor
4. Digital Devil Saga
5. Last Bible
6. Majin Tensei
7. Persona
8. Shin Megami Tense

Answer (score 1):

They are all spin-offs of Digital Devil Story, an old horror novel series about a guy who develops a computer program that can summon demons. The original Megami Tensei game was based on the story told in the novels, then came Shin Megami Tensei as a spin-off of this, with no relation whatsoever to the original story aside from the demon summoning program, and then the other games got produced with that premise in mind but all with stories of their own. So the only point in common they have is the fact that you can summon demons through a technological device.